# Detect instanceof Underscore template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, prototypal-inheritance

I would like to be able to detect if an object I'm looking at is an instance of _.template, the same way I can check for Backbone Models/Collections/Views.

for example:

```
var newView = new Backbone.View();
newView instanceof Backbone.View //true

//How I usually use template
var test = _.template("test");
test instanceof _.template //false

//When I would actually expect a successful instanceof check
var test2 = new _.template("test");
test2 instanceof _.template //false
```

I'm resorting to this instead:

```
typeof test == "function"
```

This is basically good enough for my circumstances, since I'm just wrapping my template in _.template if it's currently a string instead of an Underscore template.

However, my 2 questions -

I'm wondering if there's a way to check instanceof _.template, currently.

If not, is it prohibitively expensive to extend the template Prototype chain to allow this check? Unless it's much slower, this seems like a (minor) fault in Underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_.template` simply returns a plain old function, not an instance of anything in particular and not something that you're supposed to use with `new`, it is just a simple function.

If we have a look at [the source](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.5.1/underscore.js#L1136) (which I strongly recommend for questions like this), you'll see that the structure of `_.template` is more or less like this:

```
// A bunch of stuff to convert the template to JavaScript code
// which is combined with some boiler plate machinery and left
// in `source`
// ...
render = new Function(settings.variable || 'obj', '_', source);
template = function(data) { return render.call(this, data, _); };
return template;
```

So the thing you get back from `_.template(str)` is just an anonymous function, there's no special prototype chain set up and the only common thing to use with `instanceof` is `Function`. Asking if `t instanceof Function` really isn't terribly useful in this case, I don't think that will do anything that `typeof t == 'function'` isn't doing already.

However, [`_.template` will add a `source` property](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to the returned function:

> The **source** property is available on the compiled template function for easy precompilation.

So you could tighten things up by combining [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) with [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) or [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
typeof t === 'function' && 'source' in t
t instanceof Function  && 'source' in t
```

Both of those should be `true` if `t` came from `_.template` (but the converse is, of course, not necessarily true).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/a2auU/

As far as the second question goes, I can't think of how you can have `t()` and `t instanceof T` both work when `T` is not `Function` (I could be missing something obvious of course but messing with native types generally doesn't work out that well in JavaScript). If you wanted to say:

```
var t = _.template(s);
var h = t.exec(...);
```

instead of `t(...)` then it would be easy but it would be incompatible with everything that knows about Underscore templates.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [source of the `_.template` method](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-138), you'll see that you're barking up the wrong tree here - Underscore isn't instantiating a `_.template` object, it's building a new function for you by building up a string of source code and compiling it with `new Function()`. So the template function you're using is a new anonymous function, not an instance of anything.

If you really want a way to identify a template, I'd suggest decorating the `_.template` function to add some sort of flag - perhaps as a `constructor` property:

```
var originalMethod = _.template;
_.template = function() {
    var template = originalMethod.apply(_, arguments);
    template.constructor = _.template;
    return template;
}

var t = _.template('Foo <%= bar %>');
t({ bar: "baz" }); // "Foo baz"
t.constructor === _.template;  // true
```

Comment: How safe/reliable is it to mess with [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) though? Something like `template.is_underscore_template` might be a better idea.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't matter at all in this case, and the OP seemed to want something idiomatic.

Comment: It *shouldn't* matter but it feels like poking a hornet nest with a stick.

Comment: I can see your point, but to the extent that anyone uses `constructor`, it's often to do things like `new t.constructor("Foo <%= baz %>")` - which would work here. I suppose I'm playing Devil's advocate, since I wouldn't actually do this in my code, but I think it's perfectly safe. Backbone does something quite similar to set and reuse the `constructor` of extended classes.

Comment: I probably won't use this, but it's also probably technically closer to the answer I was asking for. Many thanks to both of you.